# How to create a div with a specified innerHTML and store it into a variable for future use?

Tags: javascript

I created two createCardNote function
First one pull data information from the state.countries
Second is from state.borders

in the createCountryCardNode, console.log(cardDiv) has value thus can be seen in the console

However, createBorderCardNode, console.log(borderDiv) has no value at all

Both codes are the same why has different outcomes?

```
function createCountryCardNode(country) {
const cardDiv = document.createElement('div');
cardDiv.className = 'country';

cardDiv.innerHTML = `
<img class="country__img" src="${country.flag}" />
<div class="country__data">
  <h3 class="country__name">${country.name}</h3>
  <h4 class="country__region">${country.region}</h4>
  <p class="country__row"><span></span>${country.population}</p>
  <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${country.languages[0].name}</p>
  <p class="country__row"><span></span>${country.currencies[0].name}</p>
</div>`;

console.log(cardDiv);
return cardDiv;
}

function createBorderCardNode(border) {
const borderDiv = document.createElement('div');
borderDiv.className = 'country';

// console.log(border.flags.svg);
// console.log(border.name.common);
// console.log(border.region);
// console.log(border.population);
// console.log(border.languages[0].name);

borderDiv.innerHTML = `
<img class="country__img" src="${border.flags.svg}" />
<div class="country__data">
  <h3 class="country__name">${border.name.common}</h3>
  <h4 class="country__region">${border.region}</h4>
  <p class="country__row"><span></span>${border.population}</p>
  <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${border.languages[0].name}</p>
  
</div>
`;

console.log(borderDiv);
return borderDiv;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would check out [mcve].

Comment: please show the function call code also.How did you pass the parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "*console.log(borderDiv) has no value at all*"? Does it log the value `undefined`? Does it not log anything at all?